# Order, Product and ProductVariant association through OrderItem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm working on an e-commerce backend using Rails 7. I'm trying to sort out the relationship between Order and Product models.

A product has many variants, so I added a relationship like this, which works fine.

**Product**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :product_variants, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**ProductVariant**

```
class ProductVariant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Next is the relationship between orders and products. Since one order can have many products, I added a third model called OrderItem. OrderItem migration looks like this:

```
class CreateOrderItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :order_items do |t|
      t.references :order, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :product, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :product_variant, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :quantity
      t.decimal :unit_price
      t.decimal :sub_total

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Order**

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_items
end
```

**OrderItem**

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  has_one :product
  has_one :product_variant, through: :product
end
```

I'm expecting to implement an order with many order_items, an order_item should have only one product, and it may be possible to have one product_variant if the customer picked a product_variant when the product is variable (some products may not have variants, and in such case, the product_variant reference can be empty and only have a reference to the product).

I'm doing something wrong with the product_variant association with order_item model, which I want help to figure out.
With the current association structure, when I try to run `OrderItem.new.product_variant` gives me an error:  `` `check_validity!': Could not find the source association(s) "variant" or :variant in model Product. Try 'has_many :variant, :through => :product, :source => <name>'. Is it one of category or variants? (ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError) ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it contains the foreign keys, `OrderItem` should `belongs_to :product` and `belongs_to :product_variant` (not `has_one`).